# How to prevent user from setting the end date before the start date using the Shiny dateRangeInput

Tags: r, date, shiny, lapply

I have a shiny app that a user selects multiple date ranges and I would like to prevent the user from setting the end date before the start date using the dateRangeInput in the lapply function. How do I code this in R? Thanks for looking into this.

Here is my code

```
       library(shiny)

       ui <-fluidPage(
              checkboxInput("add_trend", "Add Trend(s)"),
              conditionalPanel(condition="input.add_trend === true",
                               numericInput("numoftrends",
                                            label="Number of Linear Trends:",
                             min = 1,
                             max = 10,
                             value = 1,
                             step = 1),
                             uiOutput("num_of_trends"),
                             textOutput("see_ranges")
                ),
             actionButton("submit", "Submit")
        )

       server <- function(input, output, session) {

         output$num_of_trends <- renderUI({
            lapply(1:input$numoftrends, function(i) {
                  dateRangeInput(paste0("date_range_input", i), 
                          paste('Trend Date Range Input', i, ':'),                                                      

                          separator = " - ",
                          format = "yyyy-mm",
                          startview = 'year',
                          start = "2001-01-01",
                          end   = "2020-12-31",
                          min = "2001-01-01",
                          max = "2020-12-31"
                         )
                })  
           })

       trend_list <- reactive({
           out <- list()
          for(i in 1:input$numoftrends) {
           out[[i]] <- input[[paste0("date_range_input", i)]]
            }
          out
       })

        output$see_ranges <- renderPrint({
           print(trend_list())
         })
      }

       shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, to not complicate it unnecessarily I will show you a possibility for one `dateRangeInput()`.

In a nutshell: Store the start and end date in a `reactiveValue()` and set some restrictions for their updates.
As an example i chose to set the start and end date equally if your restrictions are violated.

```
  global <- reactiveValues(start = "2001-01-01", end= "2020-12-31")

  observe({
    dates <- input[[paste0("date_range_input", 1)]]
    if(!is.null(dates)){
     if(dates[1] <= global$end){
       global$start <- dates[1]
     }else{
       # date smaller than start value not allowed
       global$start <- global$end
     }

     if(dates[2] >= global$start){
       global$end <- dates[2]
     }else{
       # date greater than end value not allowed
       global$end <- global$start
     }
    }
  })

  output$num_of_trends <- renderUI({
      dateRangeInput(paste0("date_range_input", 1), 
                     paste('Trend Date Range Input', 1, ':'),
                     separator = " - ",
                     format = "yyyy-mm",
                     startview = 'year',
                     start = global$start,
                     end   = global$end,
                     min = "2001-01-01",
                     max = "2020-12-31"
      )
  })
```

For a full version with multiple `dateRangeInput()` see below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <-fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("add_trend", "Add Trend(s)"),
  conditionalPanel(condition="input.add_trend === true",
                   numericInput("numoftrends",
                                label="Number of Linear Trends:",
                                min = 1,
                                max = 10,
                                value = 1,
                                step = 1),
                   uiOutput("num_of_trends"),
                   textOutput("see_ranges")
  ),
  actionButton("submit", "Submit")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  global <- reactiveValues(start = "2001-01-01", end = "2020-12-31")

  observe({
    global$start <- as.Date(c(global$start, as.Date(rep("2001-01-01", input$numoftrends))))[1:input$numoftrends]
    print(global$start)
    global$end <- as.Date(c(global$end, as.Date(rep("2020-12-31", input$numoftrends))))[1:input$numoftrends]
  })

  observe({
    for(i in 1:input$numoftrends){
      dates <- input[[paste0("date_range_input", i)]]
      if(!is.null(dates)){
        # print(global$end[i])
        if(dates[1] <= global$end[i]){
          global$start[i] <- dates[1]
        }else{
          # date smaller than start value not allowed
          global$start[i] <- global$end[i]
        }
        # print(global$start[i])
        if(dates[2] >= global$start[i]){
          global$end[i] <- dates[2]
        }else{
          # date greater than end value not allowed
          global$end[i] <- global$start[i]
        }
      }
    }
  })

  output$num_of_trends <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:input$numoftrends, function(i) {
      dateRangeInput(paste0("date_range_input", i), 
                     paste('Trend Date Range Input', i, ':'),
                     separator = " - ",
                     format = "yyyy-mm",
                     startview = 'year',
                     start = global$start[i],
                     end   = global$end[i],
                     min = "2001-01-01",
                     max = "2020-12-31"
      )
    })
  })

  trend_list <- reactive({
    out <- list()
    for(i in 1:input$numoftrends) {
      out[[i]] <- input[[paste0("date_range_input", i)]]
    }
    out
  })

  output$see_ranges <- renderPrint({
    print(trend_list())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi BigDataScientist. Thank you for your time into looking into this code. I understand that my code is complex using the lapply function for dateRangeInput. I am new to R and Shiny and sitll learning the ins and out of this language. I was hoping to use the observeEvent for this process where you update the end date depending on the start date input of the user in order to prevent him setting the end date before the start date. We could probably use the UpdateDateRangeInput in the observeEvent.

Comment: However I do not know how to use this in the observeEvent when you have multiple date ranges. I could code it using a single date range. Hope you could help since you have a lot of experience in R and shiny, Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1) it is not about complex code, in the end its not that comlex. It is about having a generic question/answer that other users having similar questions can profit from 2) and in the end we are here to assist from bringing your from your attempt to a solution,..not write complete code. 3) so i would expect you if you can code it for a single dateRange that you show us the code and not let redo it another time???

Comment: for a version with multiple dateRangeInputs see the edit.

Answer (score 3):

I have run across this but solved it in a different way.  I just assume that the user has selected the date range they want and then use max and min.

```
start<-min(dates)
end<-max(dates)
```

Problem solved.  Works for user who is confused.